# Передача данных внешнего запроса в подзапрос

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb, подзапрос

Нужно получить обновления и количество пользователей, интересующихся обновлениями. Для этого надо в подзапрос передать `a.id`, но при попытке выдается ошибка:

> Неизвестный столбец 'id' в 'where clause'

Структура БД:

```
announcements: id          |  title 
favorites: announcement_id | user_id
```

Запрос:

```
SELECT a.title, a.id, f.rating 
FROM announcements as a, 
     (select announcement_id, count(*) as rating 
      from favorites 
      where favorites.announcement_id = a.id
     ) as f
```

Как правильно передать данные в подзарос? И если это невозможно, то как обойти проблему?

PS Использую phpmyadmin, СУБД mysql версии 10.1.38-MariaDB, движок innodb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В MySQL кореляционныe подзапросы не поддерживаются в `FROM` выражении. Перенесите подзапрос в `SELECT` лист:

```
select a.title, a.id, (
    select count(*) 
    from favorites as f 
    where f.announcement_id = a.id
    group by announcement_id) as rating 
from announcements a
;
```

Ряд производителей БД, например, [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/queries-table-expressions.html#LATERAL%20Subqueries) или [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABCJCAG), поддерживают введённый в SQL:1999 стандарте так называемый *lateral derived tables* синтаксис.
Тогда запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
select a.title, a.id, f.rating 
from announcements a, lateral (
    select announcement_id, count(*) as rating 
    from favorites f 
    where f.announcement_id = a.id
    group by announcement_id
) f
;
```

Comment: запрос: `select a.id, a.title, f.rating from (select title, id from announcements) as a, lateral (select count(*) as rating from favorites where a.id = favorites.announcement_id) as f ` выдает синтаксическую ошибку. Использую phpmyadmin, СУБД mysql версии 10.1.38-MariaDB, движок innodb. В интернете видел статьи о том что mysql не поддерживает `lateral`. Это так? Есть альтернативы?

Comment: или запрос `select a.title, a.id, f.rating from announcements as a, lateral (select count(favorites.user_id) as rating from favorites where a.id = announcement_id ) as f limit 30`

Comment: Добавте какую СУБД вы используете прямо в вопрос.

Comment: использую phpmyadmin, СУБД  mysql

Comment: Вы это уже писали в комментарии выше. Надо включить эту инфоромацию в вопрос кнопкой [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/993300/edit). Я изменил ответ. Посмотрите, поможет вам в решении?

Comment: Спасибо большое, я люблю вас)) Вы мне спасли ^_^

Comment: Пожалуйста! Если вы ещё отметите ответ как принятый (галочка слева от ответа), то о вашей любви ко мне узнают все участникии, после чего они проникнутся к нам  нескрываемой  симпатией.

Comment: )) Сделано 6_6 ;)